# How to compare a date from mysql with current date and send a notification email

Tags: mysql, email, date, compare

I have database entrys that have a date column ( mySQL date type ). I want to compare that date with the current server date and with 3 days before that day, every month, to automatically send an email to a specified address.

Comment: Depends on programming language and platform.

Answer (score 9):

you can also use the simpler MySQL [TO_DAYS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) function :

```
SELECT email FROM table WHERE TO_DAYS(date)=To_DAYS(NOW())-3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Well this is just a mock but you could try something like this:

$localTime = `date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`

// Query MySQL to get datetime

// compare the two times and send email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either make PHP or MySQL do the dirty work for you, either a script or a SELECT statement.

```
<?php
// We shall assume that you have a array called $send_date with values in the format YYYY-MM-DD (MySQL Date Format).
// These values will be the values in the date column, and this script will send the email 3 days before those dates.

$today = date("U");
// Work out, in seconds, the amount of time beforehand you would like to send the email.
$warning = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
foreach($send_date as $timestamp)
 {
  $sd = strtotime($timestamp);
  // If $sd is not an integer, it is not a valid timestamp. Move onto the next.
  if(!is_int($timestamp)) continue;
  $diff = $timestamp - $today;
  if($diff > 0 && $diff <= $warning)
   {
    function_to_send_your_email($row_id_of_this_particular_date);
   }
 }
```

Or a SELECT statement:

```
$warning = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
$today = date("U");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE TIMESTAMP(date_column) BETWEEN '.$today.' AND '.$today + $warning.';';
// Perform query, and act on results brought back.
```

The only problem with this script, and PHP in general, is that it will only check the three days (or the value stated in `$warning`) in advance only when the script is run. If you want it to keep checking I suggest you set up a CRON job.
And I can't garantee that either of these will work as I haven't checked them.

Hope this gives you some inspiration on the matter!